# Slow right -> New on File Explorer click on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry

I noticed a really weird situation on my Windows 10,
When I press right-click it works good and immediately, but then, when I go to the "New" section, it takes FOREVER, like 5 seconds which is A LOT if you think about it and really count this time for a moment.

I tried various things to solve this solution:

1. Restart the computer of course.
2. I tried many Registry editors to remove as much stuff as possible from Right-click -> New, I came to a situation I can only do New Folder, and even then, it was the same, still takes a lot of time to show up.

Any suggestions on how could this problem be solved?

Comment: To my knowledge it always takes long for that action to load, because it has to query data from a lot of sources.

Comment: @LPChip it wasn't like that before! usually when I used to right click and press New it poped up immediately! moreover, I just checked on two different PCs to verify that.

Comment: I would suggest open the registry editor - Regedit.exe. Right click on HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT and search for ShellNew. For each entry you find check that the FileName, ItemName, iconpath values where exist looks OK. I suspect that Explorer is trying to find a icon or a path under these keys that either doesn't exist, etc.

Comment: @HelpingHand i don't know if it looks good or not, but i tried to disable all of them via some registry editors and the problem kept.

Comment: See this answer for troubleshooting procedure...https://superuser.com/a/976515/40928

Comment: @Moab are you sure it should work on my case? because I saw the topic's problem and it another problem, not like mine